# Is there a way to get the history of the size of each Table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We're trying to manage costs of BigQuery storage.
In order to do that we're trying to access the history of the size of each table.
I know you can access the size of a table by using the `dataset.__Tables__` table.
I tried to access this table at a specific timestamp :

```
bq cp dataset.__Tables__@1630422245000 dataset.1630422245000
```

Doesn't Work.

I also tried to use directly in a query the :

```
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP("2021-08-31 00:00:00+00") )
```

It doesn't work either.
I don't know if there is a way to access this information ?

Obviously in the future it would be easy to monitor the size of each table whith the current data, but I want to investigate a price increase that happened previously.

Comment: According to BQ documentation,  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF can be used to query historical data for the passed 7 days only. It also says "If the timestamp specifies a time from more than seven days ago or from before the table was created, then the query fails and returns an error".

One thing that comes to my mind if you want to jump to a specific day and know the size of your table would be restore that table at that time and then check the size of the new table before deleting it 
Here's the link to the time travel doc: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#restore-a-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can access the historical data stored in BigQuery using time travel, but the data can be accessed from any time point only **within the last seven days**. Therefore, when you are trying to access BigQuery table data for 31st August 2021 (more than 7 days ago) BigQuery will return similar error like:

> Invalid snapshot time 1601168925462 for table
> myproject:mydataset.table1@1601168925462. Cannot read before
> 1601573410026.

The 7-day limit is also applicable when accessing historical data by [restoring](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel#restore-a-table) a table(from a specific point in time). The same applies for deleted or expired tables.

To be able to persist the data for more than 7 days, [table snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-intro#table_snapshots) can be created. With table snapshots you can preserve your table's data from a specified point in time for as long as you want. Snapshots are affected by the time travel limitation as well (i.e) you can only take a snapshot of a table's data as it was seven days ago or more recently.

Comment: Thanks ! 
So yeah for looking at a specific increase some time ago it won't be possible.
I'll just look at it manually, and then from now on we'll try to save the sizes somewhere. Thank you !